# Is it possible to exclude jquery from jquery dependent plugins in bundle?

Tags: jquery, webpack, webpack-4

I have bundle with jQuery and some other global plugins.
Also I have bundle with "fancybox" plugin, bundle with "swiper" plugin. (They are jQuery plugins, but don't include jQuery and work on my jQuery bundle)

But, "tooltipster" plugin bundle, includes it's own jQuery. Same with "jquery-validation" plugin...

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Suddenly, i found a solution in webpack configuration.

```
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/